# Reflection in constructor with inheritance (Java)

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, java-8, static-typing

I'm having trouble making reflection in a class constructor work with inheritance. Specifically I would like to get all attribute values.

Here is a demo for the naive implementation which doesn't work:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SubInitProblem {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Child p = new Child();
  }
}

class Parent {
  public int parentVar = 888888;

  public Parent() throws IllegalAccessException {
    this.showFields();
  }

  public void showFields() throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field f : this.getClass().getFields()) {
      System.out.println(f + ": " + f.get(this));
    }
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  public int childVar = 999999;

  public Child() throws IllegalAccessException {
    super();
  }
}
```

This will show that `childVar` is zero:

```
public int Child.childVar: 0
public int Parent.parentVar: 888888
```

Because it's not initialized yet.

So I guess I'll need to not use the constructor directly, but rather let the constructor complete and *then* use `showFields`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class SubInitSolution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalAccessException {
    SolChild p = SolChild.make();
  }
}

class SolParent {
  public int parentVar = 888888;

  protected SolParent() {
  }

  public static <T extends SolParent> T make() throws IllegalAccessException {
    SolParent inst = new SolParent();
    inst.showFields();
    return (T) inst;
  }

  public void showFields() throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field f : this.getClass().getFields()) {
      System.out.println(f + ": " + f.get(this));
    }
  }

}

class SolChild extends SolParent {
  public int childVar = 999999;

  public SolChild() throws IllegalAccessException {
  }
}
```

But that doesn't work because `make` doesn't return the correct type for subclasses. (So the problem is `new SolParent();`).

What is the best way to solve this? **I need all subclasses to execute `showFields`, but I can't rely on them doing it explicitly.**

Comment: In your second example, why implementing a `make` method ? Why not just do `new SolChild().showFields();`

Comment: Don't call such methods from a constructor. They don't contribute to initialization and therefore don't belong in constructors.

Comment: @ToYonos Because then people who use my class might forget to do that

Comment: @LewBloch Perhaps, but where else should I put things that need to happen for each instance?

Comment: @Mark to make each constructor call some method, this method needs to be placed in that constructor. But compiler can't make someone add specific method call in their constructor (even if they extend your class). I have a feeling that we are facing here [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Mark an easier alternative is to have an `init` or `start` method and document the fact that it needs to be called before the object is used. So basically create a lifecycle contract for those types of objects.

Comment: @assylias It does appear that that might be the easiest way. Without knowing language specifics, it seems like having it called automatically would be preferable. But perhaps that's not the Java way (/ doable in Java).

Comment: You can’t make the `SolParent()` constructor `private`. If you do that, subclasses are impossible.

Comment: @Holger Oops fixed tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your showFields method needs to traverse the class hierarchy, something like this:

```
public void showFields() throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> clz = this.getClass();
    while(clz != Object.class) {
        for (Field f : clz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            f.setAccessible(true);
            System.out.println(f + ": " + f.get(this));
        }
        clz=clz.getSuperclass();
    }
}
```

Note that I used [`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--), not [`Class.getFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields--), because the latter only processes public fields.

---

And this is how you can construct your classes in a generic way:

```
public static <T extends SolParent> T make(Class<T> type) throws Exception {
    Constructor<T> constructor = type.getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    T inst = constructor.newInstance();
    inst.showFields();
    return inst;
}
```

Note that this will only work if your subtype of `SolParent` has a public no-args constructor (or no constructor at all).

Comment: `make` will still create an instance of the parent, not the child.

Comment: While that makes sense, I don't think that's the problem. The attributes on parents are already found, child ones just isn't initialized yet. EDIT: about your edit, I'm not sure what `Class<T> type` is, I'll look into that and come back

Comment: @Mark it means that you can pass any Class that extends SolParent, including SolChild.

Comment: @Holger okay, changed the answer to invoke constructor directly, including private constructors

Comment: Does the constructor have to be public, or can it be protected? If it's public, people can still create instances without `make` (and consequently `showFields`)...

Comment: @Mark it can have any visibility. That's what the `.setAccessible(true)` is for

Comment: Ah because of the last sentence. Okay, pity about the argument to `make` and no arguments on the constructor, but it looks like the best approach available, thanks!

Comment: @Mark You can of course add parameters to the method and use these for constructor resolution (frameworks like Spring do that), but things get very shaky soon